# Docker image seemingly having missing layers

Tags: macos, docker

I'm experiencing some apparent strange behaviour with a docker build, resulting in the image missing some binaries. It almost seems as if some layers are actually missing from the image.

The hierarchy is thus:

```
java:8
  |
  -> localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock
     |
     -> localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres
```

Containers ran from "php-cli-wiremock" have all the expected binaries (java, php-cli, wiremock)

Containers ran from "php-cli-wiremock-postgres" only have (php-cli, wiremock, postgres). i.e. they lack the /usr/bin/java. It would almost appear as if the java:8 layers are dropped, yet they appear in the `docker history` as shown below.

I am confident that these binaries aren't deleted in any steps of the "php-cli-wiremock-postgres" build.

### Building the images

**"java:8" Dockerfile: **

https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/baaaf7714f9c66e4c5decf2c108a2738b7186c7f/8-jre/Dockerfile

**"php-cli-wiremock" Dockerfile**:

```
# combination of wiremock and php-cli. Combination is necessary to allow use with shippable.com
FROM java:8


# ----- wiremock ----
ENV WM_PKG_NAME wiremock
ENV WM_VERSION 1.57

# ----- php-cli ----
ENV PHP_VERSION 5.6.24
ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php
ENV PHP_BUILD_DEPS bzip2 \
        file \
        libbz2-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libreadline6-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxslt1-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        libnewt-dev


# ----- wiremock ----
RUN \
  cd / && \
  wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/$WM_VERSION/$WM_PKG_NAME-$WM_VERSION-standalone.jar && \
  mkdir /$WM_PKG_NAME && mv $WM_PKG_NAME-$WM_VERSION-standalone.jar /$WM_PKG_NAME/$WM_PKG_NAME.jar

# ----- php-cli ----
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl libxml2 autoconf \
    gcc libc-dev make pkg-config nano less tmux wget git postgresql libpq-dev \
    $PHP_BUILD_DEPS $PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS \
    --no-install-recommends && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3 0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 \
    && mkdir -p $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d \
    && set -x \
    && curl -SL "http://php.net/get/php-$PHP_VERSION.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror" -o php.tar.bz2 \
    && curl -SL "http://php.net/get/php-$PHP_VERSION.tar.bz2.asc/from/this/mirror" -o php.tar.bz2.asc \
    && gpg --verify php.tar.bz2.asc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/php \
    && tar -xof php.tar.bz2 -C /usr/src/php --strip-components=1 \
    && rm php.tar.bz2* \
    && cd /usr/src/php \
    && ./configure \
        --with-pdo-pgsql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin \
        --with-config-file-path="$PHP_INI_DIR" \
        --with-config-file-scan-dir="$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d" \
        $PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS \
        --disable-cgi \
        --enable-bcmath \
        --with-bz2 \
        --enable-calendar \
        --with-curl \
        --with-gd \
        --with-jpeg-dir \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --with-mcrypt \
        --enable-pcntl \
        --with-openssl \
        --with-xsl \
        --with-readline \
        --with-zlib \
        --enable-zip \
        --with-newt \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    && { find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin -type f -executable -exec strip --strip-all '{}' + || true; } \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false -o APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false $buildDeps \
    && make clean \
    && pecl install ncurses \
    && pecl install newt \
    && cd /opt \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && ln -s /opt/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar \
    && chmod +x phpunit.phar \
    && mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

RUN groupadd -r app -g 433 && \
    mkdir /home/app && \
    useradd -u 431 -r -g app -d /home/app -s /bin/sh -c "Default application account" app && \
    chown -R app:app /home/app && \
    chmod 711 /home/app


# ----- shippable.com ----
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y install curl lsb-release && \
    echo $(lsb_release -c -s) && \
    export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)" && \
    echo $CLOUD_SDK_REPO && \
#    export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-jessie" && \
    echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -qq -y install google-cloud-sdk

# ----- php-cli ----
COPY files /
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /


# ----- wiremock ----
COPY wiremockCacheFiles/__files /wiremock/__files
COPY wiremockCacheFiles/mappings /wiremock/mappings
#VOLUME ["/wiremock/__files", "/wiremock/mappings"]

#WORKDIR /opt/app

# Define default command.
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
#ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar wiremock.jar

# ENTRYPOINT pwd && ls -la



# Expose ports.
#   - 8080: HTTP
EXPOSE 8080
```

**"php-cli-wiremock-postgres" Dockerfile**:

```
# combination of wiremock and php-cli and postgres. Combination is necessary to allow use with shippable.com
FROM localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock:latest


# explicitly set user/group IDs
#RUN groupadd -r postgres --gid=999 && useradd -r -g postgres --uid=999 postgres

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.7
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ca-certificates wget

# make the "en_US.UTF-8" locale so postgres will be utf-8 enabled by default
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

ENV PG_MAJOR 9.5
ENV PG_VERSION 9.5.4-1.pgdg80+1

RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-common \
    && sed -ri 's/#(create_main_cluster) .*$/\1 = false/' /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf \
    && apt-get install -y \
        postgresql-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \
        postgresql-contrib-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# make the sample config easier to munge (and "correct by default")
RUN mv -v /usr/share/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/ \
    && ln -sv ../postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/ \
    && sed -ri "s!^#?(listen_addresses)\s*=\s*\S+.*!\1 = '*'!" /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && chown -R postgres /var/run/postgresql

ENV PATH /usr/lib/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/bin:$PATH
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data
#VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

#ADD postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql
ADD postgresql.conf /postgresql.conf
COPY initdb.sh /
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
#CMD ["postgres"]
```

**Output of `docker history localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres:latest`:**

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
b6243b6f44fc        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 5432/tcp              0 B
cb7b81da3181        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entry   0 B
b6b3fd7e0e82        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:26fb846861d8cff95   97 B
e6cbbd72e89a        3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:d243227d56acbcd72   2.585 kB
5e382c77c42b        3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7b8d8ca4cd55918f07   20.35 kB
863f87e01e58        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PGDATA=/var/lib/postgr   0 B
82802fc4c604        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/lib/postgres   0 B
7e9e650a6cb7        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && ch   0 B
abebf727dda1        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mv -v /usr/share/postgresql/$PG_MA   21.2 kB
34ffb57d5713        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install   37.32 MB
1b71dfd71e40        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.or   66 B
a1b89989f99d        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PG_VERSION=9.5.4-1.pgd   0 B
2c8e74826c5b        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PG_MAJOR=9.5             0 B
11d2cea562f6        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sk   4.538 kB
a69a87fa5b1d        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    0 B
ba64506ab206        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=en_US.utf8          0 B
0eda09bda60d        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    1.615 MB
407fa3abad4a        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update && apt-g   5.311 MB
93a992be78cd        13 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7         0 B
c34f75bb6766        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080/tcp              0 B
52f497e39022        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entry   0 B
279ea458dc03        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:06f3e18251708036e7   90.57 kB
856c03093adf        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:7cdd5a4c14b18f4563   13.43 MB
0f2ed69fb1ad        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:dead660e078f1fb15   294 B
f707ffb0d62e        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:0c1885686e63beacf7   72.24 kB
cac987db82a8        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:86af9edc26a678a31a   1.919 kB
b24972a0f508        15 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y i   89.63 MB
32be14c196e3        21 hours ago        /bin/sh -c groupadd -r app -g 433 &&  mkdir /   147.2 kB
319d2f4a017f        21 hours ago        /bin/sh -c gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyserver   132.8 MB
0cd53bbacb64        2 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    203.1 MB
f473448176dc        2 days ago          /bin/sh -c cd / &&   wget https://repo1.maven   6.936 MB
270334f34e77        2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PHP_BUILD_DEPS=bzip2     0 B
e5c040ab4015        2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local   0 B
c7e46e9e4df7        2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PHP_VERSION=5.6.24       0 B
37ec6aa6e336        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV WM_VERSION=1.57          0 B
0f0168d4061c        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV WM_PKG_NAME=wiremock     0 B
69a777edb6dc        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates   418.2 kB
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update  && apt-   349.3 MB
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VE   0 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u1   0 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_VERSION=8u102        0 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/   0 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c {   echo '#!/bin/sh';   echo 'set    87 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV LANG=C.UTF-8              0 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.   61 B
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    1.286 MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    122.6 MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    44.3 MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:0e0565652aa852f620   125.1 MB
```

At first the "missing" layer ID had my spider senses twitching but this is apparently due to some internal layer key referencing changes in Docker 1.10. These layers, however, are the ones from the java:8 build. The full --no-trunc version is here - http://pastebin.com/0VcBTAVc

### Running the images

**php-cli-wiremock**

`docker pull localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock:latest; docker run -it --rm localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock:latest ls -l /usr/bin/java`

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 10 18:41 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java`

**php-cli-wiremock-postgres**

`docker pull localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres:latest; docker run -it --rm localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres:latest ls -l /usr/bin/java`

`ls: cannot access /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`

### Notes

- I am running this on Docker for Mac with a containerised private registry (localhost:5000)
- Docker version is 1.12
- I have run with `docker build --no-cache`

### Inspect outputs

**java:8**

`Matthews-iMac:container-management matt$ docker inspect java:8
+ docker inspect java:8
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:69a777edb6dcb32c2e717f69f281ee405cef6deac6de24520aefe76594a6eae5",
        "RepoTags": [
            "java:8"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "java@sha256:1064e0e67166f8859dd7e1aa1104ffc00133bcf19dbd426447cce6f90319031e"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2016-08-10T18:41:32.240355112Z",
        "Container": "b8c4a5096022b105ae0795a451a259263077e32c1b546406eb176bffa337b815",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "2da0903ff372",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u102",
                "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1",
                "CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:16b9751e127e1164753a577be9cab63f2c878012f936cfaf4c3ac44e37d6ca49",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "1.10.3",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "2da0903ff372",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u102",
                "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1",
                "CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/bash"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:16b9751e127e1164753a577be9cab63f2c878012f936cfaf4c3ac44e37d6ca49",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 643047426,
        "VirtualSize": 643047426,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:2f71b45e4e254ddceb187b1467f5471f0e14d7124ac2dd7fdd7ddbc76e13f0e5",
                "sha256:66d8e5ee400cb0660c8c0ad51d30d822365a995eb90d35750a1e641cae7c887c",
                "sha256:1050aff7cfff31f37ff91f26ebe8583521a9329da5a7d179400228551b1506cf",
                "sha256:c6952565c883c0d36287bfa0dadfe1caa2a5b8a92b10413dc0747396aae87fd4",
                "sha256:a0163fd1c828b8da7e032443fa62e41c4dc8d8275419ae9e6b9f43a36162faaf",
                "sha256:1a6f9199aa61e7043b82e2c69556ea17c72183c3dbca3276b08cdfdca6ee61aa",
                "sha256:5778f887b92c3a990e398921f0eac0c5ddac01d90ee0af731a1f7a2cf13b1463",
                "sha256:e4ecd84596333b047c22385770f8325c18dab2157505917006c0cb6436071695"
            ]
        }
    }
]`

**php-cli-wiremock-postgres**

`+ docker inspect localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres:latest
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:b6243b6f44fc3dff8cbbcbc91fc3715e136c3a65141744e5b3373454702f37ae",
        "RepoTags": [
            "localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "localhost:5000/php-cli-wiremock-postgres@sha256:0546a57c3b35742b2e1b2eaad583529ba69086fcfc23172fdf39ac7da360be19"
        ],
        "Parent": "sha256:cb7b81da318114a78b5aec213677af517c294225fca54c523ce6d850daaa8fed",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2016-08-26T11:52:20.102044903Z",
        "Container": "98db8815817150473887720b87d61143fa0890b100a7085e82a08bab3ddf2c08",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "2da0903ff372",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u102",
                "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1",
                "CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324",
                "WM_PKG_NAME=wiremock",
                "WM_VERSION=1.57",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.24",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_BUILD_DEPS=bzip2 \t\tfile \t\tlibbz2-dev \t\tlibcurl4-openssl-dev \t\tlibjpeg-dev \t\tlibmcrypt-dev \t\tlibpng12-dev \t\tlibreadline6-dev \t\tlibssl-dev \t\tlibxslt1-dev \t\tlibxml2-dev \t\tlibreadline-dev \t\tlibncursesw5-dev \t\tlibnewt-dev",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "PG_MAJOR=9.5",
                "PG_VERSION=9.5.4-1.pgdg80+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "EXPOSE 5432/tcp"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:cb7b81da318114a78b5aec213677af517c294225fca54c523ce6d850daaa8fed",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "1.12.0",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "2da0903ff372",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u102",
                "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1",
                "CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324",
                "WM_PKG_NAME=wiremock",
                "WM_VERSION=1.57",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.24",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_BUILD_DEPS=bzip2 \t\tfile \t\tlibbz2-dev \t\tlibcurl4-openssl-dev \t\tlibjpeg-dev \t\tlibmcrypt-dev \t\tlibpng12-dev \t\tlibreadline6-dev \t\tlibssl-dev \t\tlibxslt1-dev \t\tlibxml2-dev \t\tlibreadline-dev \t\tlibncursesw5-dev \t\tlibnewt-dev",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "PG_MAJOR=9.5",
                "PG_VERSION=9.5.4-1.pgdg80+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:cb7b81da318114a78b5aec213677af517c294225fca54c523ce6d850daaa8fed",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 1133462572,
        "VirtualSize": 1133462572,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:2f71b45e4e254ddceb187b1467f5471f0e14d7124ac2dd7fdd7ddbc76e13f0e5",
                "sha256:66d8e5ee400cb0660c8c0ad51d30d822365a995eb90d35750a1e641cae7c887c",
                "sha256:1050aff7cfff31f37ff91f26ebe8583521a9329da5a7d179400228551b1506cf",
                "sha256:c6952565c883c0d36287bfa0dadfe1caa2a5b8a92b10413dc0747396aae87fd4",
                "sha256:a0163fd1c828b8da7e032443fa62e41c4dc8d8275419ae9e6b9f43a36162faaf",
                "sha256:1a6f9199aa61e7043b82e2c69556ea17c72183c3dbca3276b08cdfdca6ee61aa",
                "sha256:5778f887b92c3a990e398921f0eac0c5ddac01d90ee0af731a1f7a2cf13b1463",
                "sha256:e4ecd84596333b047c22385770f8325c18dab2157505917006c0cb6436071695",
                "sha256:942a8ea4fa066724a265d07c7d35f6c45f393d1ce914f8ca40d83e99af65bf85",
                "sha256:94a8ddf232d34524edf57c10e86aecdc87c5e6b28c35bbace94b68197a36b609",
                "sha256:003a5be98635727e92806f0c7961f4d8f7281a7289389acfb55145966f4d424e",
                "sha256:d615c4e8af228c611c96d3d9867f2d9f9a90200e6cfffeaf777ac0374cb476b7",
                "sha256:5dee5fbf6d8f7117e2a9f759612b5c875610d1b378b48030be9ce0703385164c",
                "sha256:fb09a6741ff94b60f5a9dc292fd13fc0d6a19eaba49d6b8eebbd677467d66574",
                "sha256:049561e8ed827b1a45d57148442c313af7585572d224ebe2a8338d9970febe14",
                "sha256:838640dbcacdaafacb5fab5b53d4118ad42a6a7cc221c49cc0ab497ee8fc9322",
                "sha256:385eb0d637e83a16a7848b37eb0532bb96c8a87aa88da7a8e479b0cd9d6568d7",
                "sha256:b01776fa0320292eeb78b5bdf9f3154627d57ea8c691f7f6e54686eba2785d9f",
                "sha256:adcebb7a5f805da7487b7b7a28addebe5260861ef238f32fd60bb663388962f7",
                "sha256:74bf92ac3fdd233ca67fd82bd7af11ffb46a77575a670b7b5eef1f26cc076766",
                "sha256:939e18c0cc00dfc57f2474ca1078996038ebe0ef66a54ebd58d5534769a239e2",
                "sha256:20a1c7a1d1d224dc5d14ebd4118dd41b6f836903d0c0bb17c82d39ce5b80d68d",
                "sha256:a073365847a62f6d5bedd4d85cfba0d64fc17dd9f3d3fd04ef38416709b0570f",
                "sha256:a66bd2f198ff2b97a46edb3b9fd7339ef29a3df9a08a2047d0d87d21105260a9",
                "sha256:515034b141d70165c0d589777b1115ca18c601bdaddd6d44ead95a8056c7eade",
                "sha256:9bb3e8a75f5fc430427a8a3c76e3be31ef471dd129b767667ceb74d63c41e8a3",
                "sha256:a4df8a72c1e91d9c07c219667e48f7a197baee694ada5098da2c5689fae6068e",
                "sha256:3380f90fc77766f3268563948a9bddac916dbcb30748bd3e06acc119deee962f",
                "sha256:0306af8e0aff6d94becb4bd7fa4f7943b2187253cfd3b6e54ea488d5429ef926"
            ]
        }
    }
]`

Comment: You can run any of those intermediate image id's to see what layer causes the files to go missing.

Answer (score 1):

Docker has a layer limit, and that is were you are running into. Try to merge as many RUN Statements as possible, using ’&&’. yes, this means you will not be able to group your sections as you did sementically but rather by statement type and dependency order

http://www.extellisys.com/articles/docker-layer-overload